# subject and verb in "The average bundle price paid"?

Tags: verbs, subjects

I found this sentence really confusing:

> The average bundle price paid was a little over $8.

So, *the average* is the subject. *Paid* is the verb. What about the *bundle price*?

Can we use this form instead?

> The average *paid bundle price* was a little over $8.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the entire sentence.

Comment: @BarrieEngland sorry about that >_< 

Edited !!

Comment: I think the verb is *was*. You can remove the word *paid* without significantly affecting the meaning, and it's really only acting as another adjective modifying *price*, the same as *bundle* does. Unless you "promote" it somehow, by saying, for example, *"The average bundle price **advertised** was 5, but in fact the average bundle price **paid** was a little over 8, because of non-advertised additional costs"*.

Answer (score 8):

In “The average bundle price paid was a little over $8”, *price* or *bundle price* is the subject and *was* is the verb.  *Average* modifies *bundle price* or *bundle price paid*.  In any case,  “average bundle price paid” is a noun phrase forming the subject of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for putting in the rest of the sentence - it makes analysis possible.

Leaving out the word 'paid' leaves us with the sentence

**The average bundle price was a little over $8.**

Here, it is obvious that the subject is 'The average bundle price'. There follows a copular structure; the verb involved is **be** ('was').

A 'bundle price' is a collocation possibly best regarded as a compound noun:

"...savings based on comparison of Bundle price with price of same services sold separately. ..." (Google)

and 'average' is an adjective in attributive position (actually a rather difficult type of adjective to classify - but that's not germane here).

Putting 'paid' back into the reduced sentence, it is seen to be relating to the noun group ('bundle price'); if we had 'paid by the people in the showroom' we would see it is an adjectival non-finite clause postmodifying the noun group. The shorter version 'paid' is syntactically the same.

Answer (score 3):

“The average bundle price paid”
1) *Price* is the subject.
2) *Bundle* is a noun used as an adjective.
3) *Average* can be a noun or an adjective. In this sentence it is an adjective.
I see nothing wrong with that sentence.
I mean, there are two adjectives (*average* + *bundle*) giving qualities to one noun (*price*).